# MySQL structure for translations

Tags: mysql, database, multilingual

According to this approach, default language is **already translated** in first table. If a user doesn't need a translation, he won't struggle with them. Just connect primary table, that's all...

PRODUCT TABLE (InnoDB):

```
 Obj_id(PK)             name                    desc
 ---------      -------------------     ------------------
     1          Million Dollar Baby    Short description is...
     2          Music Album            Another explanation...
```

TRANSLATION TABLE (InnoDB)

```
 trans_id (PK)    Obj_id (FK)   lang      field              trans
--------------   -----------   ------    --------    ---------------------
      22              1          TR        name       Milyonluk Bebek
      23              1          BA        name       Djevojka od milijun...
      24              1          TR        desc       Kisa açiklama burada
      25              1          BA        desc       Kratki opis je ovdje
      26              2          BA        name       Glazba albuma
```

But the problem occurs when administrator wants to change default language. I have two options to solve this problem:

1. Administrator has to decide default_lang at the beginning of the project and if he still wants to change default_lang in the future, the program will say: `Go to hell`.
2. Like first solution, admin has to decide default_lang at first, but the system will be able to transfer new default_lang data from translation table to primary table (i don't do this actually).

I think my solutions are not good enough.

Do you have better idea about DEFAULT_LANG problem with or without change the structure (if it's possible, don't change the structure - i like it)?

Comment: +1 for the `Go to hell` message to Admin.

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if having a table per language would be better. That way you'd just switch out tables that are being used.

```
TRANSLATIONS_TR
TRANSLATIONS_EN
TRANSLATIONS_FR
TRANSLATIONS_BR
```

Then in your user display routines, you decide what table to query when displaying translation text.

Answer (score 1):

gettext solves a different kind of problem than a multilingual database: gettext is for the UI, while the database is for the content.

You'd use gettext or equivalent for fixtures like error messages, a button label or a page title, where there's a small list of items that change infrequently.

A multilingual database is for large volumes of content that may or may not change frequently, like, say, the titles of hundreds of thousands of books and movies, or descriptions for tenders.

Comment: the problem with gettext for me (i used it for Wordpress translations before) is synonyms. For instance I use `Class` two different places in my software (one of them for `categorizing`, another for `school class`). That works with English, but when I want to translate it, that's problem for other languages. Maybe gettext solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

My approach I think it would be (I'm in the process of building this myself):

Maybe (1)Product has (N)Names (depending on language, assuming you only have one column describing the language, like 'es', 'en')

```
[ Product ]—(1)—————(N)-[ProductName]
|    id   |             | name      |
                        | language  |
```

Maybe it's better Product-Language in a N:M relationship:

```
[ Product ]-(N)—————————(M)-[Language]
|   id    |        |        |iso_code|
             (translation)  | name   |


[   Product   ]<————[ProdTranslation]———>[language]
|    id       |     | name          |    |iso_code|
|default name?|                          | name   |--- (name of language: "English")
```

Another option could be to consider each translated of the product to be a "type of" Product (a subclass). Logical model follows:

```
[   Product   ]
|    id       |-(1)————(1)-[ EnglishProduct ]
|default name?|            | name (in eng.) |
|             |
|             |-(1)——(1)-[FrenchProduct]
|             |          | name(in fr.)|
```

When implementing this in a relational database, then you could either a) have 3 tables (in this example, more with more languages) or b) put it all in one table. It depends on how many languages you would have, size of the name/description, performance, etc.

```
[ Product ]
| id      |
| name_en |
| name_fr |
| name_de |
```

The code querying the database would know the language to be used, and then query the name from the right column.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into gettext?

http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/

Comment: @progrsm...  the problem occurs when administrator wants to change default language in the future.. so i have to transfer NEW DEFAULT_LANG from TRANSLATION table to PRODUCT (PRIMARY) TABLE.

Comment: @dino I'm not sure how your idea was about gettext, but it's very simple. You have all the translations in gettext for each language. In database you have only the "default" language. You fetch for example "Music Album" call gettext and ask it for a specific language. Bang you have it. Fast and simple guaranteed!

Comment: something to add, to put the translation into the database is a BAD idea. Gettext is your friend.