# Search in database with country name in different language

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a search page where user can make search for visiting places of the different countries. In the database the address is stored in the English language and the result is shown from '%like%' query. It will give right result whenever someone search the address in the English language but no result found when someone search in the other language. I have tried to make change the search term in the English language and then make query but I has also a limitation. So what will I do to make my search work perfectly.
Please help

Comment: You will need a translation table / dictionary inside your database to extend the used query or create a two-step search mechanism (i.e. query a translation service prior to searching your database).

Answer (score -1):

Please check your field collation. It should be utf8_general_ci.

May this links will help you.

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724551/converting-mysql-database-to-support-multiple-languages)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949642/mysql-structure-for-translations)

[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097827/create-a-two-languages-translator-with-mysql-php)